# How do i override Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

I have made some changes to Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http but in the file distributed by with magento. This is not the best way, i know, but i have not been able to work out how to override a file in the Controller directory. I can find out how to override files in the controllers directory.

Can anyone tell me how i can override Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http in my own extension.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating observers, to listen to certain pre-dispatch events that you could easily override? Why override / extend the entire "Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http" class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to revert to the include path hack, you can also use reflection to set your own request class on the `Mage_Core_Model_App` model. You can use an observer for `controller_front_init_before` event for that.
I'll assume you are familiar how to create an event observer, soI'll only add the code for the observer method. If you need additional information please ask.

```
// Observer method
public function controllerFrontInitBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $app = Mage::app();
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($app);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('_request');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $myRequest = new Your_Module_Controller_Request_Http();
    $myRequest->setOrigRequest($app->getRequest()); // if needed
    $property->setValue($app, $myRequest);

    // Proof of concept:
    // Loggs Your_Module_Controller_Request_Http
    Mage::log(get_class(Mage::app()->getRequest()));
}
```

Create the class `Your_Module_Controller_Request_Http` and extend the original `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`.
After that event your request object will be used instead of the original.

This enables you to stay as upgrade safe as possible, because you do not have to copy over the full class from the cor code pool.

Comment: Thanks Vinai. This was making my head steam :)

Comment: A warning for Enterprise Edition users: this will break the FPC, as the processor is re-routing the request to _pagecache/request/process_ before the _controller_front_init_before_ event, so when replacing the request object you have to copy the needed informations to the new one.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: Vinai's solution is the better one.**

Because this class is instantiated directly, you will have to use the so-called **include path hack** to override.

The order of precedence for include paths which affect `Varien_Autoload`'s work is set in `app/Mage.php`. That order is as follows:

1. `app/code/local/`
2. `app/code/community/`
3. `app/code/core/`
4. `lib/`

Therefore, if you copy your file to an analogous path under the `local` or `community` codepools, your definition of that class will be used.

Comment: Go with Vinai's solution, MUCH more elegant!

Comment: Thanks for explaining what is going on!

Answer (score 2):

Since Magento 1.7 you can use the method `Mage::app()->setRequest($request)` to replace the request object within an observer for the `controller_front_init_before` event as suggested by [Vinai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201013/418614).

**WARNING for Magento Enterprise:** The Full Page Cache won't work with this method, as it relies on changes to the request object done before `controller_front_init_before`. You either need to manually copy all properties from the old request to the new - or replace the request class with [benmarks solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200826/418614).