# Override Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http

Tags: magento, url

I want to just edit one line which is: 137
I want to change:
$requestUri = $this->getRequestUri();
to
$requestUri = urldecode($this->getRequestUri());

I want to override it in custom module not to edit in core files.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199854/how-do-i-override-mage-core-controller-request-http), but it didn't work for me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you attempt extending the controller as suggested by Ben Marks in the [solution you linked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199854/how-do-i-override-mage-core-controller-request-http)?

The observer method is ideal though I don't understand the context of what you are attempting to do so extending the controller would be the next ideal thing.